# Split horizontally after installing treemacs

Tags: window-splitting, treemacs

I have installed treemacs package and I have enabled it in init.el file to open the treemacs on start-up. However, this also splits my window horizontally as in the picture below. I do not want the *scratch* buffer, I just want the file I opened on the right of the treemacs. How can I disable this split horizontal behavior? (The way I opened the emacs in the picture below is typing emacs ./init.el on Ubuntu terminal)

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: Does this split happen when you do not automatically start treemacs ?

Comment: No, it does not open. The split only happens when I call emacs with a file name as an argument. If I call just emacs without any arguments, there is no split as intended.